# Mvvm - How to capture in the ViewModel, which Button was pressed, using dataBinding command and Parameter Command? What am I not getting?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, command

To simplify, Criticized for writing a novel w/no code a month ago, I made a quick wpf project (uses MVVM) with 2 buttons on the UI.
 When a button is clicked, I need my ViewModel to know which one, to route the Speech Synthesizer to the correct Text to Speak. Thanks 4 any help!!

[Simple UI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5FGF.jpg)

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_School_Announce.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_School_Announce"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Wpf_School_Announce.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Announcements" Height="236.436" Width="293.218">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModelBase x:Key="viewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source=viewModel}">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,10">
            <Button x:Name="btn1stBell" Content="1st Bell" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="0,10" 
                     Command="{Binding ParameterCommand, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Command, ElementName=btn1stBell}"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnLunchMenu" Content="Lunch Menu" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="0,10"
                     Command="{Binding ParameterCommand, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Command, ElementName=LunchMenu}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


namespace Wpf_School_Announce.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase
    {
        public ParameterCommand ParameterCommand { get; set; }

        public ViewModelBase()
        {
            ParameterCommand = new ParameterCommand(this);
        }

        public void ParameterMethod(string <Not sure what needs to go here>)
        {
           Debug.WriteLine("Parameter Comand:{0}", AnnoucementModel);
            //Todo: Need to find out which UI button was clicked to direct The Speech Synthesozer to the correct Speech Text.
        }
    }
}

namespace Wpf_School_Announce.ViewModels.Commands
{
    public class ParameterCommand : ICommand
    {
        public ViewModelBase ViewModel { get; set; }

        public ParameterCommand(ViewModelBase viewModel)
        {
            ViewModel = viewModel;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ViewModel.ParameterMethod(parameter as String);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ElementName=LunchMenu` no, you use ElementName to rebase the binding.  Since the binding is already set on LunchMenu, you don't need to do that.  Also, rebasing causes the binding to execute against the control, not the DataContext of the control.  You could have used Snoop to see this at runtime.  I'd suggest you get it.  You can set CommandParameter to be the name of the sound you want to play, and get that value when Execute fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad solution to just have one command on your viewmodel and to bind every button to it. If you have different things to be executed, define different commands. For that you either have to define a separate class with a dedicated `Execute` metod for each command or you can use something like `RelayCommand` of [MvvmLight](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Command/RelayCommand.cs), where you can pass delegates upon creation of each command like this

```cs
public class ViewModelBase 
{
   public RelayCommand BellCommand...
   public RelayCommand LunchCommand...

   public ViewModelBase()
   {
      this.BellCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ExecuteBell);
      this.LunchCommand = new RelayCommand(this.ExecuteLunch);
   }

   private void ExecuteBell(object Parameter) {...}
   private void ExecuteLunch(object Parameter) {...}
}
```

and in your XAML

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=BellCommand}"... />

<Button Command="{Binding Path=LunchCommand}" ... />
```

This way you have separate places for the individual logic and your viewmodel must not know anything about your ui - which is good.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `It is a bad solution to just have one command on your viewmodel and to bind every button to it` is debatable. If the command is indeed exactly the same, but takes a different parameter, you can also use the `CommandParameter` property.

Comment: Agreed, if the logic behind the commands is the same (like e. g. `next` / `prev` on a pagination). Here I felt (by the given names of the commands) this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

**XAML:**

```
<Button CommandParameter="command_name" Command="{Binding OnClick}" Content="Click Me"></Button>
```

**Event.cs:**

```
using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Input;
       private ICommand onClick;
       public ICommand OnClick
      {
       get
       {
       return onClick ?? (onClick = new RelayCommand(clickSwitch));
       }
    }
```

**Class.cs:**

```
private async void clickSwitch(System.Object obj)
     {
      switch (obj.ToString())
       {
        case "command_name":
        //code
        break;
    }
```